# How do I display text from firestore data in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase/firestore and wanted to add firestore to my app. My app currently has a login and adds data to the database with the UID set as the document name. [Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CRnT.png)
I want to display the name in my apps profile page. How would I achieve this?

Called it with this

```
Center(child:building(context),),
```

```
  Widget building(BuildContext context) {
    return new StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('UserData')
            .document(getUID())
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return new Text("Loading");
          } else {
            return new Text(snapshot.data.toString());
          }
        });
  }
```

Current Error
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbOz0.png)

Previous Error

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC1Ky.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is `usersPosts`?

Comment: Oh I forgot to update that it should look like this `Firestore.instance
                      .collection('UserName')
                      .document()
                      .snapshots(),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 Widget building(BuildContext context) {
    return new StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('UserData')
            .document('TjMJDFd940UtLORgdYND771GYwG2')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return new Text("Loading");
          } else {
            Map<String, dynamic> documentFields = snapshot.data.data;
            return Text(documentFields["First Name"] +
                " " +
                documentFields["Last Name"]);
          }
        });
  }
```

Note that `TjMJDFd940UtLORgdYND771GYwG2` refer to documentID.

Comment: I tried that and got this error type `'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Comment: can you print out this line `snapshot.data.toString()` ? Check what value is this

Comment: `Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('UserData').document(getUID()).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return new Text("Loading");
        }else{
          return new Text(snapshot.data.toString())`
         }
   
      }
  );
}

Comment: I got the following error `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Comment: Yes, I copy-pasted and called it like this `build(context),`

Comment: Never work with firestore, but let us debug one by one. Try `Firestore.instance.collection('UserData').snapshots()`.

Comment: Ok there is no error now but it is displaying - Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'

Comment: You printing `snapshot.data` or `snapshot`?

Comment: `Widget building(BuildContext context) {
    return new StreamBuilder(
        stream:Firestore.instance.collection('UserData').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return new Text("Loading");
          } else {
            return new Text(snapshot.data.toString());
          }
        });
  }`

Comment: can you post your code to github ? It hard to debug like this

Comment: (https://github.com/KingRegera/NuevaApp/tree/master/Nueva) here is the link to app

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I forgot to set it to public. Here is the link I should work now - https://github.com/KingRegera/NuevaApp

Comment: can you allow me to access your firebase too ?

Comment: what is the email and password?

Comment: I can't give my password since my account contains important data. I can give you access to my specific firebase project and give you the role as editor if you send just your email address.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for the Flutter Firebase API are stashed away and are admittedly hard to find.  [Here's the documentation on the QuerySnapshot class](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html).

You are trying to look at the `.document` property of a `QuerySnapshot` object, so it's throwing an error because that property does not exist. Try using `snapshot.documents` to get a list of documents to iterate over (or just use `snapshot.documents[0]` if there will always only be one), and then read the data from that, i.e.: `snapshot.documents[0].data[documentId]['First Name']`. I removed quotes from `documentId` reference, since we want to index the variable value and not just the string "documentId".

Comment: `Center(
                    child: StreamBuilder(
                  stream: Firestore.instance
                      .collection('UserName')
                      .document()
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final documentId = getUID();
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading...');`

Comment: `return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['First Name'])
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                )),` 
like this and it gave an error Class
`'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: documents` 
I think I made a mistake somewhere.